# Pentaho map values to field after join

Tags: join, google-analytics, mapping, pentaho, pdi

I am doing a data source integration using Pentaho Data Integration where I need to join a table A with multiple Google Analytics data streams (Lets call them GA_A, GA_B, GA_C, ... GA_Z).All the GA streems have the same fields, but they come from different profiles. I am using a LEFT OUTER JOIN in each merge step to keep all the data from table A while adding the values of each GA data stream. The problem is that, when I make the joins, all the GA fields from each data stream are added to the result but renamed with an underscore. Here is an example:

GA_A , GA_B and GA_C all have the field "name" and are joined to the table A. In the last join result, I get the fields "name" , "name_1", and "name_2").

This obviously happens because of the nature of the LEFT OUTER JOIN. However, I want to "map" of "send" all the values from "name_1", "name_2", "name_3", etc to the field "name". How can I achieve this? I see that there's a "Value Mapper" step in PDI, but I don't want to use a step for each of the 10 fields I bring from GA (also, I'm not sure if that step does what I want to do)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an image of your transformation? There are a couple of ways to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brian.D.Myers said there are multiple solutions available.

First, if all the GA streams are of the same structure there is no need to use join for all of them - you can first union all data (just directing them to a same step i.e. Dummy step) and after do the join - in that case you won't get multiple name_* fields.

However if there are still fields having the same name in table A and GA stream - they will obviously be renamed with underscores (it is essential as you pointed out). To handle this there ar few options:

1. If you need to just copy values - use the [Set field value](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Set+field+value) step - it copies a value from one field to another
2. If there is some complex processing logic - use the Javascript step
3. If streams are relatively small and you actually need to retain both fields - you may use the "Stream lookup" step instead of Merge join - it will allow you to specify names of the "merged" columns so no naming conflicts occurs.

Comment: The solution to my union problem was sending all the GA steps to a select values step. However, Pentaho still fails to join all the union data with the other table. Still, solved the union issue. Thanks!